# How to fix JMeter Sample Start:1969-12-31 19:00:00 EST issue?

Tags: jmeter

I'm working on testing a SFTP and use the plugin SSH protocol support. I faced with a wrong data issue:

```
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-2
Sample Start:1969-12-31 19:00:00 EST
Load time:0
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:0
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Connection Failed
Response message:Failed to connect to server: Auth fail
```

I found the same problem [Apache.org](https://lists.apache.org/thread/5o8j8zdxb8hd79h4xz1m2pwxz9o4o24j)
I use: JMeter5.5, SSH Protocol Support, 3 Basic Graphs

And I guess I can fix it if I manually set the current date. I believe the JSE223 PreProcessor can do it. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the issue with the [SSH Sampler plugin](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) and I guess in order to fix it the plugin developer needs to properly call [SampleResult.sampleStart()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#sampleStart()) and [SampleResult.sampleEnd()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#sampleEnd()) everywhere.

The real "fix" would be raising an [issue](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler/issues) or coming up with a pull request.

---

When an unexpected (any) error occurs the start time is being set to the beginning of the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) by default so the "fix" would be fixing your Sampler in a way it woudln't fail.

In unlikely case of using JMeter for funcitonal [negative testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_testing) (i.e. you expect the Sampler to fail due to incorrect login) you can workaround the issue by adding a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and putting the following code into "Script" area:

```
prev.setStampAndTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), 1)
```

where `prev` stands for the aforementioned [SampleResult](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know how to do load testing in this situation? Worked fine yesterday. I have already reinstalled everything twice, disabled unused plugins. Maybe there is an option to set up SampleResult.sampleStart() and SampleResult.sampleEnd() in Pre/PostProcessor or somewhere else?

Comment: And I checked the code in the plugin, it has SampleResult.sampleStart() and SampleResult.sampleEnd()

Comment: The weird thing is it worked a day before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my mac(m1). After installing any plugin, all files and folders updated to 01/01/1970. Just modifying to the right date helps to run test, anyway if it has any error it still shows 1969/12/31.